# Google sheets, how to create a table of Vlookup and get the last occurrence for each customer

Tags: google-sheets

I have a database of customers, where his zone, seller and some other values can change, and I want to generate a table of the last occurrence of each one

[Heres a demo sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1uBJ78onE7Iv76pT6b1Zn-fwJNYD_9JXh6CcCRcpguWA/edit?usp=sharing)

[image]

using Vlookup doesn't get the last occurrence

My database is very big and I need something to not slow my sheet that much, because I was using a formula like this one for each cell

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(LOOKUP(2,1/(C2:C=A2),$D$2:$D))
```

but the sheet is very slow because of this

Any help on this please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use:

```
=ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(SORTN(SORT({C3:E, B3:B}, 4, 0), 9^9, 2, 1, 1), 9^9, 3)
```

[image]

Comment: that works , is there a way you can explain me a little more how this works for the future ? and other side if I want to get for example columns D,E,F, J,K ? but not G,H,I

Comment: @UnionMovil sure. we combine the desired range with column of dates in array `{ }` then we sort it based on date column in descending order. then we use `SORTN` to return all rows (`9^9`) and perform grouping mode of sortn (`2`) on the first column in our C:E range (`1`) in ascending order (`1`). next we wrap it into array-constrain and outputting all rows (`9^9`) and first 3 columns (`3`)

Comment: thank you for that explanation, very helpfull

Comment: if I want to get for example columns D,E,F, J,K ? but not G,H,I ... bes idea is wrap it into a query and just select the desired columns to show ? or would be a better approach for that ?

Comment: can you share some sample?

Comment: I the same demo sheet I created another tab for that sample

Comment: see your sheet `=ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(SORTN(SORT({C3:F, J3:K, B3:B}, 7, 0), 9^9, 2, 1, 1), 9^9, 6)`